# CountDown Script, Doesn't display or countdown correctly

Tags: javascript, html, function, for-loop, countdown

so I've been tyring to debug my script for my pomodoro(tomato) clock. What I want this script to do is it will recieve input(in minutes). Right now what my script is doing is counting down by 5 instead of 1 seconds. Also it will not display the minutes like I want it too.

I made the script in a logical way to log to console and test it. What I see in the console is it displays every second, but it displays 5 seconds every second if that makes sense. Here is the jsbin: https://jsbin.com/gigohajawo/3/edit?js,consolehttps://jsbin.com/gigohajawo/3/edit?js,console

Here is the code, any help would be appreciated!!!

```
//makes sure the page is loaded first
$(document).ready(function() {
    //global variables
    //grabs text of an id and converts it to an int
    var countMin = 5;
    var count1 = 60;


    //when button id "but" is clicked...

       //while page is up, it keeps track each second that has passed
       for(; countMin >=0;countMin--){
            var counter1 = setInterval(function(){
                //calls timer function to count down
                 count1 = Timer(count1,counter1,countMin);
            },1000);
          count1 =60;
        }



    //counts down
    function Timer(count,counter,minutes){
        count--;
        //once it hits 0 seconds, the interval will stop counting
        if(count <=0){
            clearInterval(counter); 
            return count;
        }

        //displays the countdown
        if(minutes < 10){
            if(count < 10){
                console.log("0:0" + count);
            } else {
                console.log("0:" + count);
            }
        }else if(minutes > 0 && minutes < 10){
            if(count < 10){
                console.log("0" + minutes +":0" + count);
            } else {
               console.log("0"+minutes+":" + count);
            }
        } else{
            if(count < 10){
                console.log(minutes+":0" + count);
            } else {
               console.log=minutes+":" + count;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

});
```

Comment: The problem is that you are creating 5 interval functions that will all trigger at the same time.

Comment: But how am I creating 5 interval functions? I must not understand how the setinterval function works

Comment: In your for loop, you are calling `setInterval` 5 times (Once for each time through the loop), since there is a slight delay between each one being created they all print out in the correct order at the same time (Hence why you are getting 5 seconds displayed at a time). See my answer below for what I believe to be a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://jsbin.com/wefozat/1/edit?js,console) JSBin seems to do what you intended.

The code:

```
//makes sure the page is loaded first
$(document).ready(function() {
    //global variables
    //grabs text of an id and converts it to an int
    var count1 = 120;

    // Call a function every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
    var counter1 = setInterval(function() {
      count1 = Timer(count1, counter1);
    }, 1000);


    //counts down
    function Timer(count,counter){
        // Decrement the seconds counter
        count--;

        // Get the minutes and seconds in whole numbers
        var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
        var seconds = count % 60;

        // Once it hits 0 seconds, the interval will stop counting
        if(count <=0){
            clearInterval(counter);     
        }

        // Pads the seconds with a 0
        if (seconds < 10) {
          seconds = "0" + seconds;
        }

        // Pads the minutes with a 0
        if (minutes < 10) {
          minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }

        //displays the countdown
        console.log(minutes + ":" + seconds)

        return count;
    }

});
```

Please note:

1. Since you have defined `count1` as a global variable you do not need to pass it into `Timer`
2. The same goes for `counter1`

If I was rewriting it I would do something like this:

```
//makes sure the page is loaded first
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeInSeconds = 120;

    var timeCounter = setInterval(function() {
      timeInSeconds--;

      // If we hit 0 seconds clear the timer
      if (timeInSeconds <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timeCounter);
      }

      // Display the current time
      displayTime();
    }, 1000);


    function displayTime(){
        // Get the minutes and seconds in whole numbers
        var minutes = Math.floor(timeInSeconds / 60);
        var seconds = timeInSeconds % 60;

        // Pad with zeros using the Ternary operator
        seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

        // Display the countdown
        console.log(minutes + ":" + seconds)
    }

});
```

Comment: Wow, looks like I was over complicating my code. Yours is a lot simpler and cleaner. From what I learned from your code is that I don't understand the setInterval function.

Comment: @jediderek, the `setInterval` function will call what ever function you specify every `1000` (In this case) milliseconds. It won't stop until you `clearInterval`. I think you mostly got it, just had a slight confusion with your `for` loop.

Comment: @jediderek, if this answer has resolved your issue, feel free to mark it as such. :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying,